# pygame collisions y axis not working

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I am making a topdown survival game. A problem with my collisions:

I am making the player collide with a bench, the problem is, the x axis collisions work, but the y axis collisions don't even detect.

```
if playerx + playerw > 268 and playerx < 368 and playery + playerh > 392 and playery < 442:
    if playerx + playerw > 268 and playerx + playerw < 275:
        playerx -= 5
    if playerx > 360 and playerx < 368:
        playerx += 5
    if playery > 430 and playery < 441:
        playery += 5
    if playery + playerh > 386 and playery + playerh < 392:
        playery -= 5
```

the code is obvious, playerx = players x coords ,, playery = players y coords ,, playerw = players width ,, playerh = players h ,, the 268, 368, 392, and 442 are the bench top left and bottom right coords.

Again, I can collide on the left and right, but not up or down, any solutions?

EDIT:

Fixed half of it, the bottom, left, and right collisions work, not the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `392` in the first line to `386`. You're setting the wrong limit so that check is ignored.

```
if playerx + playerw > 268 and playerx < 368 and playery + playerh > 386 and playery < 442:
```